# navigation bar issue - need help for personal website, needs two links to drop down on already formatted code

Tags: html, css

I can not figure out how to add dropdown links for the two links on my site. I also have two nav codes and I am unsure which is which?

```css
nav.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.nav-wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.nav-wrapper li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div.nav-wrapper li a {
  color: #fff;
}

*start of a new code,
that I am not sure matters?* .navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  color: #800000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">

    <li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">&nbsp;About</a></button>
    
      <!-- drops down to "your crew" -->
      
      <li><a href="crew.html">&nbsp;Your Crew</a></li>
      <li><a href="rates.html">&nbsp;Rates</a></button>
      
        <!-- drops down to "fishing charters, boat rentals, and how-to fishing seminars" -->
        
        <li><a href="charters.html">&nbsp;Fishing Charters</a></li>
        <li><a href="rentals.html">&nbsp;Boat Rentals</a></li>
        <li><a href="seminars.html">&nbsp;How-to<br> Fishing <br>Seminars</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">&nbsp;Fishing Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="gear.html">&nbsp;Gear</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">&nbsp;FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">&nbsp;Contact</a></li>
        
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What's with all the Lorem Ipsum?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't add Lorem Ipsum to get around the rules which are in place to help guide people toward writing questions that can be answered. Consider wrapping those `<li>` elements in either `<ul>` or `<ol>` as appropriate. There is an unmatched closing div near the end of the nav section.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution according to me for your problem will be to create a css dropdown. I cannot demonstrate the whole thing as this is too big of a code. But this link should definitely help you out.

[Create CSS dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text)